# How to fix Deploy failed. Could not compile models in GCP Looker (Google Cloud core)?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, looker, lookml

We are unable to deploy any LookML. It fails with:

Deploy failed. Could not compile models

(including the sample_thelook_ecommerce project)

We are using a  new Looker Instance. Looker (Google Cloud core)

Looker version 23.18.23

We have been unable to find a solution as of yet. Does anyone know how to fix this?

We have tried using bare repository, gitlab repository, advanced deployment, LookML model file only containing the minimum connection.

Minimal Reproducible Example:

1. Create authorization credentials: https://cloud.google.com/looker/docs/looker-core-create-oauth
2. Create Trial Instance (in Sydney Region): https://cloud.google.com/looker/docs/looker-core-trial
3. Make a change to the sample project and attempt to deploy it. https://cloud.google.com/looker/docs/looker-core-sample-project

[Deploy Failed Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vollP.png)
[Advanced Deploy Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DVX7M.png)